# Model of a particle in a linear box

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, electrons

I'm studying the model of a particle in a linear box when we have a chain of unsaturated carbons. I have a chain with 3 bonds and 4 atoms of carbon.

I'm applying the expression

$\lambda = \frac{8cmL^2}{ n^2 h}$

(instead of n I'm calculating the variation of n) where $c$ and $m$ are the light speed and the mass of the electron, respectively and $L$ is the length of the box ($=(3+1) \times d_\ce{CC}$, where $d_\ce{CC}=\pu{1.41E-10 m}~$ is the carbon-carbon distance), and I assume the transition with less energy is $3^2-2^2$.

I calculated 210 nm and the correct answer should be 207 nm. Am I taking an incorrect approach?

Comment: Ok, first of all you need to be way clearer in what you are saying. It took me a while to figure out what you were even trying to calculate, because you didn't say what $\lambda$ represented. For a while I thought you were calculating the de Broglie wavelength of the electron in the orbital. It's easy to use maths to write "the variation in $n$". All you need to do is:

$$\lambda = \frac{8cmL^2}{(n_2^2-n_1^2)h}$$

where $n_2$ is the upper level and $n_1$ is the lower level. Then say $n_1 = 2$, $n_2 = 3$. Anyway, my answer is 209.76 nm.

Comment: What is a linear box? How carbons come into picture? Where does the 207nm as an answer come from?

Comment: 210 instead of 207? I'd say that's an excellent agreement for such a crude approximation.